# Event Listener functionality of the Web3.py doesn't register changes

Tags: web3js, python, morden, web3.py

I am using the python implementation of the web3 library.(https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py) 
Calling and interacting with contracts works fine, but when it comes to the event listener functionality, none of the fired events are registered by the program.

```
def transfer_callback(log_entry): print "Event fired"

filter = contract.on("DisplayChange", {})

filter.watch(transfer_callback)
```

Watching the contracts event in the Ethereum Wallet also works without problems, so the issue is definitely connected to python. 
Thank you in advance for any response.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look at the docs [here](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html#event-log-filters), the example is quite clear:

```
def new_transaction_callback(transaction_hash):
    sys.stdout.write("New Block: {0}".format(transaction_hash))

new_transaction_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
new_transaction_filter.watch(new_transaction_filter)
# each time the client receieves a unmined transaction the
# `new_transaction_filter` function will be called with the transaction
# hash.
```

another good place to look at examples on how it should be implemented is in the tests folder, specifically [here](https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py/blob/master/tests/filtering/test_contract_on_event_filtering.py)

Comment: the watch method is not present anymore i think 
`'LogFilter' object has no attribute 'watch'` web3.py 5.19

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get contract event logs

```
def transfer_callback(log_entry): 
    print "Event fired"

contract = web3.eth.contract(abi, address)
contract.on("DisplayChange", {}, transfer_callback)
```